# Proof a Subspace of V which is not 0

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $U$ which is a subspace of $V$ and $dim(U) < dim(V) - 1$. I have to proof that $W$ is a subspace of $V$, and $U$ has to be a Subspace of $W$ but $U \neq W \neq V $.

$V$ is defined as a finite-dimensional Body.

The definition $U \neq W \neq V $ rules out the Zero-Space (well I think).
Given so few information it has to be something about the natur of the subspaces itself. I think it has something to do with the Rank-nullity theorem but I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dim(V)=n$. We have $\dim(U) \leq n-2$. Consider a vector $\mathbf{x} \in V-U$. Moreover suppose a basis of $U$ is $\{u_1,u_2, \ldots ,u_k\}$. Now consider the space spanned by the set of vectors $\{u_1,u_2, \ldots ,u_k\} \cup \{\mathbf{x}\}$. This space will be our $W$. Firstly $U \subset W$ is clear. Moreover $\dim(W) \leq n-1$ because we are only adjoining one vector to a basis of $U$. So $W \subset V$.

Comment: Ok I was totally on the wrong track with this! - Thats awesome!